# Add a double bottom border and a single top border

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to add a double bottom border and a single top border for financial subtotals.

```vb
Sub CycleBd()
With Selection
    If .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone Then
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    ElseIf .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin And _
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone Then
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    ElseIf .Borders.Weight = xlThin Then
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'Clear All
        .BorderAround colorIndex:=xlAutomatic, Weight:=xlThick
    Else
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'Clear All
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Every attempt has no result and defaults to clearing borders.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're trying to do, add a 4th 'cycle'. It only checks if the top border is `xlThick` for conciseness, but you might need to change that if you add more 'cycles' in the future.

```
Sub CycleBd()
With Selection
If .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone Then
.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
ElseIf .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin And _
.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone Then
.Borders.Weight = xlThin
ElseIf .Borders.Weight = xlThin Then
.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'Clear All
.BorderAround ColorIndex:=xlAutomatic, Weight:=xlThick
ElseIf .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick Then
.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'Clear All
.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
Else
.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone 'Clear All
End If
End With
End Sub
```

I'd also add that you can add those specific styles to the quick access toolbar, so you wouldn't have to cycle through them.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I was attempting to make it cycle when all borders were thick... maybe that was my issue. The quick access toolbar is a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

The worksheet data structure is unclear. The provided code shows how to configure a double line on top border of total line.

```vb
Sub SetBorders()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    rng.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    rng.BorderAround ColorIndex:=xlAutomatic, Weight:=xlThick
    rng.Rows(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
End Sub
```

[image]